# Heroku : (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy my django app on heroku.
While deploying I am getting this error. I am not sure if there is something wrong with my settings file or heroku setup.
Python 3.10, Django 4.1.2

Here is the database settings I am using

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
}
```

This is the database url from heroku config

```
DATABASE_URL: postgres://ewdtekjzxnzuuo:b16a983b5c9cfb7fe1f9aaab58f1ac21bea073fdb059c0fa7356600c4a19030b@ec2-34-200-205-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/da0ttf53ppludi
```

Error message ->

```
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 97, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 36, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1533, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1952, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_expression_indexes
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 371, in supports_expression_indexes
    not self.connection.mysql_is_mariadb
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 439, in mysql_is_mariadb
    return "mariadb" in self.mysql_server_info.lower()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 425, in mysql_server_info
    return self.mysql_server_data["version"]
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 399, in mysql_server_data
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 694, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 323, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 299, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 281, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 263, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 247, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Let me know if there is any info required.

Comment: If that is your real database URL you should rotate your credentials **_immediately_** by running [`heroku pg:credentials:rotate`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-credentials-rotate-database). They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_.

Comment: Your application clearly isn't using your `DATABASE_URL`. Is that snippet that sets `DATABASES` the very last thing in your `settings.py`?

Comment: (Side note: I _very strongly_ advise using the same database server in development and production. These things aren't drop-in replacements for each other. Either switch to PostgreSQL locally or use a MySQL addon on Heroku.)

Comment: No, ```DATABASES``` is declared almost at the top of my ```settings.py```.

Comment: Then look at the rest of `settings.py` for places where you change its value.

Comment: Nowhere else it is changed.

Comment: Well it's clearly getting another value from _somewhere_. Do you have multiple settings files?

Comment: Yes, I do have multiple setting files, one for dev environment, another for production.

Comment: How does your code decide which settings file to use? Do any of the other ones modify `DATABASES`, specifically to configure a MySQL connection?